# What was the reason Owen Chase did not kill the gigantic whale?

Tags: plot-explanation, in-the-heart-of-the-sea

In *[In the Heart of the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Heart_of_the_Sea_(film))* I didn't understand the last part when Owen Chase had the chance to kill the whale but he spared it.
What was the significance of that particular scene?